# Logstash filter regular expression difference in JRuby and Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, jruby, logstash

The Logstash filter regular expression to parse our syslog stream is getting more and more complicated, which led me to write tests. I simply copied the structure of a Grok test in the main Logstash repository, modified it a bit, and ran it with `bin/logstash rspec` as [explained here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash#testing). After a few hours of fighting with the regular expression syntax, I found out that there is a difference in how modifier characters have to be escaped. Here is a simple test for a filter involving square brackets in the log message, which you have to escape in the filter regular expression:

```
require "test_utils"
require "logstash/filters/grok"

describe LogStash::Filters::Grok do
  extend LogStash::RSpec

  describe "Grok pattern difference" do
    config <<-CONFIG
      filter {
        grok {
          match => [ "message", '%{PROG:theprocess}(?<forgetthis>(: )?(\\[[\\d:|\\s\\w/]*\\])?:?)%{GREEDYDATA:message}' ]
          add_field => { "process" => "%{theprocess}" "forget_this" => "%{forgetthis}" }
        }
      }
    CONFIG

    sample "uwsgi: [pid: 12345|app: 0|req: 21/93281] BLAHBLAH" do
      insist { subject["tags"] }.nil?
      insist { subject["process"] } == "uwsgi"
      insist { subject["forget_this"] } == ": [pid: 12345|app: 0|req: 21/93281]"
      insist { subject["message"] } == "BLAHBLAH"
    end
  end
end
```

Save this as e.g. `grok_demo.rb` and test it with `bin/logstash rspec grok_demo.rb`, and it will work. If you remove the double escapes in the regexp, though, it won't.

I wanted to try the same thing in straight Ruby, using the same regular expression library that Logstash uses, and followed the [directions given here](http://bealetech.com/blog/2012/05/15/testing-logstash-grok-filters/). The following test worked as expected, without the need for double escape:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'grok-pure'
grok = Grok.new
grok.add_patterns_from_file("/Users/ulas/temp/grok_patterns.txt")

pattern = '%{PROG:theprocess}(?<forgetthis>(: )?(\[[\d:|\s\w/]*\])?:?)%{GREEDYDATA:message}'
grok.compile(pattern)

text1 = 'uwsgi: [pid: 12345|app: 0|req: 21/93281] BLAHBLAH'
puts grok.match(text1).captures()
```

I'm not a Ruby programmer, and am a bit lost as to what causes this difference. Is it possible that the heredoc config specification necessitates double escapes? Or does it have to do with the way the regular expression gets passed to the regexp library within Logstash?

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with writing tests for logstash before, but my guess is the double escape is due to the fact that you have strings embedded in strings.

The section:

```
<<-CONFIG
  # stuff here
CONFIG
```

Is a heredoc in ruby (which is a fancy way to generate a string). So the `filter`, `grok`, `match`, `add` and all the brackets/braces are actually part of the string. Inside this string, you are escaping the escape sequence so the resulting string has a single literal escape sequence. I'm guessing that this string gets eval'd somewhere so that all the `filter` etc. stuff gets implemented as needed and that's where the single escape sequence is getting used.

When using "straight ruby" you aren't doing this double interpretation. You're just passing a string directly into the method to compile it.